# IP address from settings is altered during start of the application

Tags: c#, .net, ip, virtualbox

I have following problem:
In my application, I have config file, which I use to alter settings needed for standalone installations of the application.
In the settings, there is variable "OffLineServerAddress", which is set to "169.254.2.2"

The application only uses this variable, it is NOT changed anywhere in the program.

The user says (and log file confirms it), that the address, which he uses, is different. It corresponds with address of his virtual box.
Default addres in app.config file is "127.0.0.1"

Apparently, the program uses ip addres of virtual box instead of address from the config file.

I can not think about any way, that this is possible and unfortunatelly I can not post here reproducible code.

I can confirm, that config file of the user has the correct ip address and that the value of the variable is not changed programmatically by the program.

Does anyone know about some way, in which this behavior could happen?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution - problem was in saving of default settings.